# How Get javascript variable value in php

Tags: javascript, php

How to get "var slider" value in php and then use the value for "WHERE" in query ? Thanks

```
  var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
  var output = document.getElementById("time");
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;

  slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;

    <?php
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM populasi INNER JOIN waktu ON populasi.idWaktu = waktu.id WHERE waktu.jam = ???? ";
      $result = $con->query($sql);
    ?>
  }
```

Comment: you cannot pass javascript variable directly to php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get javascript data like your code above, but you can use this ,
you can use jquery then use ajax

```
$.ajax({
url: 'your url to receive data or whatever',
type: 'POST / GET depend on your need',
dataType: ' can be json, text , or something else',
data:some data you wanna send to,
success:function(data){
   console.log(data);
},
error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    console.log(thrownError);
}
```

example :

```
var slider=$('#myRange');
slider.on('input',function(){
  $.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/intime', // Your url for receive data
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'text',
  data:{slide:slider.val()},// You can send multiple data like {test:test1,test2:test2, ...}
  success:function(data){
    console.log(data);// you can change this for your own function or whatever
  },
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    console.log(thrownError); // If error thrown here
  }
});
```

on server side :

```
$slider=$_POST['slide']; //Get slide from ajax
echo $slider; //you can use this var for proccessing or get query. etc.
```